# Unused parameters in routes Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.1, model-binding

I write api for mobile, since I have more than one version, I don't want to copy-paste the same routes, hence I decided to do something like this:

```
Route::model('callRequestNote', CallRequestNote::class);

Route::group([
    'prefix'     => 'api/v{version}/mobile',
    'where'      => ['version' => '[1|2]'],
], function () {
    Route::delete('/notes/{callRequestNote}', MobileNotesController::class . '@destroy');
    // other duplicated routes
});

public function destroy($version, CallRequestNote $callRequestNote)
{
    //
}
```

I use `version` parameter only in `BeforeMiddleware`, hence I don't need it in controller. My question is how to replace those parameters and make `CallRequestNote` as a first argument and get rid of `$version`?